# fetch templates from database/string

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

I store my templates as files, and would like to have the opportunity to store them also in a MySql db.

**My template System**

```
//function of Template class, where $file is a path to a file 
function fetch() {
    ob_start();
    if (is_array($this->vars)) extract($this->vars);
    include($file);
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
}

function set($name, $value) {
    $this->vars[$name] = is_object($value) ? $value->fetch() : $value;
}
```

*usage:*

```
$tpl    = & new Template('path/to/template');
$tpl->set('titel', $titel);
```

*Template example:*

```
<h1><?=titel?></h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

**My approach**

1. Selecting the the template from the database as a String
2. what i got is like $tpl = "<*h1><*?=$titel? >...";
3. Now I would like to pass it to the template system, so I extended my constructor and the fetch function:

function fetch() {

```
if (is_array($this->vars)) extract($this->vars);
ob_start();
if(is_file($file)){
    include($file);
}else{
        //first idea: eval ($file);
    //second idea: print $file;
}
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;
}
```

'eval' gives me an Parsing exception, because it interprets the whole String as php, not just the php part.
'print' is really strange: It doesn't print the staff between , but I can see it in the source code of the page. php function are beeing ignored.

So what should I try instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but its simple and it should work:

1. fetch your template from the db
2. write a file with the template
3. include this file
4. (optional: delete the file)

If you add a Timestamp column to your template table, you can use the filesystem as a cache. Just compare the timestamps of the file and the database to decide if its sufficient to reuse the file.

Comment: Yeah, I might go with that, I thought about that before :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prepend `'?>'` to your eval, it should work.

```
<?php
$string = 'hello <?php echo $variable; ?>';
$variable = "world";
eval('?>' . $string);
```

But you should know that eval() is a rather slow thing. Its resulting op-code cannot be cached in APC (or similar). You should find a way to cache your templates on disk. For one you wouldn't have to pull them from the database every time they're needed. And you could make use of regular op-code caching (done transparently by APC).

Every time I see some half-baked home-grown "template engine", I ask myself why the author did not rely on *one of the many* existing template engines out there? Most of them have already solved most of the problems you could possible have. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) (and Twig, phpTAL, …) make it a real charme to pull template sources from wherever you like (while trying to maintain optimal performance). Do you have any special reasons for not using one of these?

Comment: Because my existing template system - file based, is 1 class and about 30 lines and I can use native php in my template files. - All I want and need.
The database-feature is just an experiment, to learn more about php and might not be even used.

Answer (score 1):

I would do pretty much the same thing as tweber except I would prefer depending on the local file timestamps rather than the DB.

Something like this: Each file has a TTL ( expiration time ) of lets say 60 seconds. The real reason is to avoid hitting the DB too hard/often needlessly, you'll quickly realize just how much faster filesystem access is compared to network and mysql especially if the mysql instance is running on a remote server.

```
# implement a function that gets the contents of the file ( key here is the filename )
# from DB and saves them to disk.
function fectchFreshCopy( $filename ) {
    # mysql_connect(); ...
}


if (is_array($this->vars)) extract($this->vars);
ob_start();
# first check if the file exists already
if( file_exits($file) ) {
    # now check the timestamp of the files creation to know if it has expired:
    $mod_timestamp = filemtime( $file );
    if ( ( time() - $mod_timestamp ) >= 60 ) {
        # then the file has expired, lets fetch a fresh copy from DB
        # and save it to disk..
        fetchFreshCopy();
    }
}else{
    # the file doesnt exist at all, fetch and save it!
    fetchFreshCopy();
}

include( $file );
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;
}
```

Cheers, hope thats useful

Comment: ok, using a timestamp might be good for caching, but not good enough if the template itself doesn't change very often. Any suggestion for something like a hash? Or should I just go with a "I was changed, please get a new local copy and set me to false"-flag? {I think creating and writing the file is also 'expensive'}